# Checking NSMutableArray content

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

I'm developing an iPhone app.

I have the following **INIT** code:

```
shapes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numShapes];
```

After that, I want to do the following:

```
- (CGSize) sizeOfShapeType:(ShapeType)type{
    CGSize shapeSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    if (shapes != nil) {
        for(Object2D* obj in shapes)
            if (obj.figure == type) {
                shapeSize = obj.size;
                break;
            }
    }
    return (shapeSize);
}
```

But I always get a **EXEC_BAD_ACCESS** because all shapes in shapes array are null.

How can I check if an Object2D is null?

I get the exception here:

```
for(Object2D* obj in shapes)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

arrayWithCapacity returns autoreleased object, so you must retain it to make sure it won't get deallocated prematurely:

```
shapes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numShapes];
```

or

```
// .h file
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *shapes;
// .m file
@synthesize shapes;
// your init method
self.shapes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numShapes];
```

For the latter solution you need to declare property with retain attribute for shapes ivar.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS is probably that you don't claim ownership of the object assigned to the `shapes` variable, and not an issue with `NSMutableArray`. I'm assuming `shapes` is an instance variable. By the time `sizeOfShapeType` is called, the object stored in `shapes` has been released.

So the solution is to claim ownership.

```
shapes = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numShapes] retain];
// or
shapes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numShapes];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shapes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numShapes];
```

Have you actually created and loaded the array with Object2D objects? The above array initialisation will initialise the array with space for `numShapes` number of pointers to objects. But the array will still be effectively empty. It doesn't create any `Object2D` objects for you.

My apologies if I'm stating the obvious. But if that's all you're doing in your init code, then you've misunderstood what `arrayWithCapacity:` means.